# How can I fix the swapBack function to get the result I intended?

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I am trying to implement a swap back function that will swap the values back to the original position. This is the instruction I have to do accordingly:

Implement a second swapping
function, swapBack(int v[2]), that takes the vector v = [x, y] as an input and swaps its entries. Includes
the new function into the program above to swap back the values of x and y.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *pX, int * pY){
    int temp = *pX;
    *pX = *pY;
    *pY = temp;

}

void swapBack(int x, int y){
    swap(&x,&y);
}

int main() {
int x = 10;
int y = 5;
swap(&x, &y);
printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
swapBack(&x, &y);
printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
return x + y;
}
```

However, both `printf` produce the same results and I am not sure how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Since `swapBack` doesn't accept pointers, it's swapping its own parameters, but *not* anything in its caller.  Why don't you swap back by just calling `swap(&x, &y)` again, since you know that's working?

Comment: Alternatively, if you really want a separate `swapBack` function, it needs to accept pointers, too.

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn you about the call `swapBack(&x, &y)`.  As written, `swapBack` accepts ints, not pointers-to-int.

Comment: `swapBack()` will act as I guess you want it to act (it would help if you actually would explain what you expect it to do), only if you implement it exactly as `swap()`, i.e. only difference the name. Or if you declare the prototype identically and then internally call `swap(pX, pY)`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, I have to implement a 'swaBack'  function according to this: Implement a second swapping
function, swapBack(int v[2]), that takes the vector v = [x, y] as an input and swaps its entries. Includes
the new function into the program above to swap back the values of x and y.

Comment: @stevielol I don't understand your requirement, but: You need to pay close attention to the distinction between ints, and pointers-to-int.  And if possible, use a better compiler, that properly complains about mismatches like a function defined as `swapBack(int x, int y)` but that's called as `swapBack(&x, &y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining `swapBack` wrong. It's supposed to take an array (which decays to a pointer) of two integers.

This should be about what you want:

```
void swapBack(int v[2])
{
    int temp = v[0];
    v[0] = v[1];
    v[1] = temp;
}
```

A program to test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swapBack(int v[2])
{
    int temp = v[0];
    v[0] = v[1];
    v[1] = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int v[2] = {10, 5};

    printf("v[0] = %d, v[1] = %d\n", v[0], v[1]);
    swapBack(v);
    printf("v[0] = %d, v[1] = %d\n", v[0], v[1]);
    printf("v[0] + v[1] = %d\n", v[0] + v[1]);

    return 0;
}
```